# Couchbase internal processes taking a lot of CPU

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am using couchbase 5.0.1

Couchbase internal processes like **beam.smp, indexer and cbq-engine** are taking a lot of CPU.
Can you please tell me how to tune these processes so that they take less CPU?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's happening while this is going on?  Is the database warmed up and idle?

Comment: Issue is that we are reaching end of resources with just 2 concurrent users. This should not happen. Not sure whether DB is warmed up or idle.

Answer (score 1):

To get the load on the query engine (cbq-engine) down, you need to find out what is causing the load. This article has a lot of information about query profiling:

https://blog.couchbase.com/optimize-n1ql-performance-using-request-profiling/

Comment: Hi Johan, after upgrading to Couchbase 5.5, CPU usage for both cbq-engine and indexer is now down. But it is still high (or 10% improvement) in beam.smp